# Given a String, Move The First Letter of Each Word to The End of Each Word, Then Add "ay" To The End of Each Word and Return a New String - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, concatenation

So far I have:

```
function pigIt(str) {

  //split string into array of words
  let words = str.split(" ");

  //loop through array of words
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    //loop through individual words
    for (let j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {

      //get first word in words
      let firstWord = words[0];

      //get first character in first word
      let firstChar = firstWord[0];

      //Create new word without first character
      let unshiftedWord = firstWord.unshift(0);

      //move first character to the end
      let newWord = unshiftedWord.push(firstChar) + "ay";

      return newWord;

    }
  }
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'));
```

For now, I would just like to return `"igPay"`. Then, I will combine the strings together to form a new string.

But it doesn't like `firstWord.unshift(0);`. It's saying:

> TypeError: firstWord.unshift is not a function.

But .unshift() [is a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)? Why isn't that working?

Once I can get a new word, I should be able to combine the `newWords` together into a `newString`, although there's probably a more efficient way than creating new for-loops for each individual word.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/520b9d2ad5c005041100000f/train/javascript

**EDIT**: I'm looking to write this function with traditional function declaration, not with arrow notation.

**EDIT 2** After implementing @Ori Drori's code, my function looks like:

```
function pigIt(str) { 

  newString = str.replace(/(\S)(\S+)/g, '$2$1ay');
  return newString;
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'));
```

And it works - but I don't understand what `str.replace(/(\S)(\S+)/g, '$2$1ay');` is doing, exactly.

Comment: `firstWord` is a string. `unshift` isn't a method on string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Okay so `.unshift()` will only work for an array - not a string. I guess I could turn the string into an array?

Comment: `firstWord[0]` does **not** give you an error, since it just returns a non-existing value of property "0" of the string.

Comment: On the other hand, you have `return` inside an inner loop. How many iterations do you expect?

Comment: It should iterate through every word in the string so my `return` is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to that is using `map()` and `join()`.

**Note**: that according to codewars example only `ay` is added to string containing aplhabets not `!`. So you should test whether the the element of array is aplhabet or not using `test()`.

All the tests in the codewars are passed for following solution.

```js
function pigIt(str){
  return str.split(' ').map(x =>/[a-zA-Z]+/.test(x) ? x.slice(1)+x[0]+'ay' : x).join(' ');
}
console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'));
```

#### Without arrow function.

```js
function pigIt(str){
  return str.split(' ').map(function(x){ 
      return /[a-zA-Z]+/.test(x) ? x.slice(1)+x[0]+'ay' : x;
  }).join(' ');
}
console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'));
```

#### Simple `for` loop

Here is the code using simple `for` loop

```js
function pigIt(str){
  str = str.split(' ');
  for(let i = 0;i<str.length;i++){
    if(/[a-zA-Z]/.test(str[i])){
      str[i] = str[i].slice(1) + str[i][0] + 'ay';
    } 

  }
  return str.join(' ');
}
console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'));
```

Comment: Thank you - using the simple for loop is closest to what I was originally looking for. Though the other answers are also helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a RegExp ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OStgnl/4)) and [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The regex catches the head (1st letter) and tail (the other letters) of each word (actually sequence of non space values). Use the replacement (`$2$1ay`) to rebuild the word in pig latin.

```js
const pigIt = (str) => str.replace(/(\w)(\w+)/g, '$2$1ay')

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'));
```

How does the replace work:

- The regex collects the 1st word character (`\w`) and assigns it to `$1`
- The regex collects the rest of the word's characters and assigns them to `$2`
- The replacement defines that the new string would be $2 then $1 and then "ay"

Note: I've used `\S` to catch all non space characters.

Comment: So would this simply look like `function pigIt (str) {
str.replace(/(\w)(\w+)/g, '$2$1ay');
}` if it followed traditional function declaration like in my code?

Comment: Yes it would. The arrow `() =>` is just short for `function { return ... }` in this case.

Comment: Okay can you explain what `str.replace(/(\S)(\S+)/g, '$2$1ay')` is doing, exactly? Isn't `$` jQuery?

Comment: I've added a link to regex101 where you can get more info, but I'll add an explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`unshift` in not an method on string

You can simply split on space and than map and swap places and add `ay` and join them with space again.

```js
let str = `Pig latin is cool`

let op = str.split(' ').map(e=>  e.substr(1,) +e[0] + 'ay').join(' ')

console.log(op)
```

Without arrow function

```js
let str = `Pig latin is cool`

let op = str.split(' ').map(function(e){
  return  e.substr(1,) +e[0] + 'ay'
}).join(' ')

console.log(op)
```

Comment: @HappyHands31 i have added one, but you should learn about arrow functions too mate, this is really cool feature of JS IMO

Comment: @HappyHands31 now you know where the problem was, i suggest you give it a try again, if you still find difficulty just let me know in comment will add a version of `for loop` one too

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work and without Regex

```
function pigIt(str){
       let arr = str.split(" ");
       let newArr = [];
       for ( let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ ) {
          if ( arr[i] === "!" || arr[i] === "?" ){
             newArr.push(arr[i]);
          } else { 
             let s = arr[i].slice(1)+arr[i].charAt(0)+"ay"
             newArr.push(s)
          }
        }
      return newArr.join(" ")
    }
```